# OnSignInSucceeded is called in every activity

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am using game services in my app. i have 3 activities that each extends the BaseGameActivity.

The user has the option to sign in on the first activity only. However, everytime I go from one activity to another, onConnected from the GameHelper is called which in turn calls notify listeners and then call my "onSigninsucceeded" method. This is in every activity.

I thought that method is only called when you sign in, not for every activity. Is there anyway I can prevent that from happening?

Thank you

Comment: How do you know it's being called in each activity? Are you overriding `onSignInSucceeded()` in all of them?

Comment: Because the3 activities extend a base class that has the method overridden. I thought it would be called only in the first activity after signing in but the same toast is showing up on every activity up starting